# Dependent Dropdown Lists

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have three listboxs on a page.  The first one can be populated with one of five different options.  The second listbox will populate based on a selection of one of the five.  The third will populate based on the second.  I have the first one working fine, having major problems with the second and the third.  Here is the code that calls and populates so far.  The first box is named Doggie, the second Kitty and the third Pig.  mydoggie.php has a nested switch.  case, then type.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:image").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        display("Doggie", $(this).val());
        })


    $("Doggie").change(function(){
              display("Kitty", $(Doggie).val());
        })

        $("Kitty").change(function(){
              display("Pig", $(Kitty).val());
        });
  });

function display(what, type) {
    $.getJSON("mydoggie.php?ajax=true", { "case": what, "type" : type}, function(data) {
        $("#"+_type_).empty();
        $.each(data, function(index, objRecord) {
            $("#"+_type_).append('<option value="' + objRecord.ID + '">' + objRecord.Name + '</option>');
        });
    });
}
```

'You can see an almost working example of what I have at www.menuhead.net/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$(document).change` to `$(you kitty id list).change`...

Comment: Tried it and the listbox still did not populate. Do you need to see the mydoggie.php file?  There is a swith involved on mydoggie.php, then a switch in mykitty.php and mypig.php.